# Alternative for " in accord with our experience"

Tags: word-request

Sometimes something is easy as it is **in accord with** our experience or the way we do things.

What is the proper words instead of "in accord with"?

Comment: To answer your question Title: You could say it is **inherently** easy. But to answer your actual question, go with "intuitive", as already recommended.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock thank you for the useful word, but the word I look for should fill the gap, *easy as it is ...... our experiences and easy as it is ........... the way we do things*

Answer (score 2):

You can say "*as it **agrees** with our experience*" or "*as it **reflects** our own experience*".

Comment: What about "... the way we do things"? is it **similar to**?

Comment: What would the full sentence be?  "Sometimes something is easy because it is the way we do things." - very generic.  Perhaps "*things*" need to be replaced with "*it"*.

Comment: I want to say an application is easy to use, because in this application things are done the way we do them. you suggest no interleaving word.

Comment: I just went with your own construct ("*as it*").  If you'd like, you can use "*because*" or even "*since*".

Comment: I mean you suggest me to write "it is easy because it is the way we do things" with no other word? for example "it is easy because it is **similar to** the way we do things"

Comment: Either is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the word you're looking for is **intuitive**. If something is intuitive, then it feels natural to use; likely, doing it does not require much training or explanation.

Edit: In a sentence, you would say *the application is intuitive*

Answer (score 1):

- easy, as it is **consistent with** our...
- easy, as it is **congruent with** our...
- easy, as it **matches** our...
- easy, as it **fits with** our...
- easy, as it **follows** our...
- easy, as it **follows the pattern of** our...